# Downloaded Excel showing blank after Microsoft's security update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have exported table values to excel file through GridView using below C# code.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename="+filename+".xls");
```

It was working well until recent security update from Microsoft [security update for microsoft excel 2010 kb3115322].

After the update, I am unable to view the content of Excel file. It is showing blank excel.

After uninstalling the update I can view the Excel but I need a solution through C# code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like opening the xls file in notepad to see what's in there? maybe Excel has nothing to show, because the file's empty.

Comment: save the thingy on disk see if there you can open it, on the other hand what has excel update to do with your exported file, you are returning a file as response, are you using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Answer (score 2):

Yes due to Microsoft new security update issue is rising to current excel files format. So for solving and for a quick solution you should make csv (comma separated file) instead of xls so excel application will open the csv by ',' seperator.

**Note : I faced this issue in my Php application , and I solved by making xls file with PHPExcel library.I hope you may find something like PHPExcel for C# as well.**

Thanks. Feel free to comment.

Comment: Yes, I was able to open when I changed the format to .csv file. But it was not in proper format(alignment and look). It would be great if there is any solution without changing file format.

Comment: By changing only file extension it will not work just change your code so that it makes the file in csv format lkie

id,name,city
1,Mahamadali,Palanpur
2,ABC,XYZ

And then it will open in proper format.

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem. My solution was to rewrite all Excel exports with ExcelPack. And I used XLSX and no longer XLS.

just in case rewriting is an option for you.

https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];

//header
ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Column1";
ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Column2";
ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Column3";
ws.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Column4";
ws.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Column5";

//content
int i = 1;

foreach (Item item in list)
{
    i++;

    ws.Cells[i, 1].Value = item.Prop1;
    ws.Cells[i, 2].Value = item.Prop2;
    // format datetime
    ws.Cells[i, 3].Value = item.Prop3.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    ws.Cells[i, 4].Value = item.Prop4;
    ws.Cells[i, 5].Value = item.Prop5;
}

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=Filename.xlsx");
    package.SaveAs(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();
}
```